# JTable rendering breaks on replacing row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The program is 2 Synchronized ArrayLists that is modified by 2 threads. First thread is a socket listener which creates objects. And second is swing EDT in which button can move an object from an array 1 to array 2. Both arrays are represented as a JTable. Objects have View object inside of them which holds Component for every table cell to render. Some fields are updated real time , most are not.

When I add the first line everything works fine and then remove it from the table it , it disappears properly adding a new line in its place , the field in column 0 does not render until I click on it ,all other fields render properly. Real time field render properly.

Object visual representation class

```
public class View implements MouseListener
{
    public final List<JTextField> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
    public final List<JTextField> ratios = new ArrayList<>();
    public final kosilkshik.Position source;
    public final JTextField name = new JTextField();
    public final JTextField mkt = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(mktTime), 2);
    public final JTextField p = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(pTime), 2);
    public final JTextField flip = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(flipTime), 2);
    public final JTextField current = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(currentQty), 2);
    public final JTextField qt = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(getQty()), 2);
    public final JTextField buy = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(buyAt), 2);
    public final JTextField sell = new TextFieldNumber(String.valueOf(sellAt), 2);
    public final JTextField avg = new JTextField(String.valueOf(average), 2);
    public final JTextField bid = new JTextField(String.valueOf(average), 2);
    public final JTextField ask = new JTextField(String.valueOf(average), 2);
    public final JCheckBox invert = new JCheckBox();
    public JButton control;
    public JButton control1;
    public JButton control2;
    public JButton control3;
    {
        bid.setEditable(false);
        ask.setEditable(false);
        avg.setEditable(false);
        name.setText(makeName());
        name.setEditable(false);
        name.repaint();
        name.addMouseListener(this);
    }
    View(kosilkshik.Position p)
    {
        source=p;
        for(TwsConnect.Position c:source.contracts)
        {
            symbols.add(new JTextField(c.contract.localSymbol,15));
            ratios.add(new JTextField(String.valueOf(c.getQty()),2));
            symbols.get(symbols.size()-1).setEditable(false);
            ratios.get(symbols.size()-1).setEditable(false);
        }
        invert.addActionListener(source);
        delete.setActionCommand("delete");
        use.setActionCommand("use");
        send.setActionCommand("send");
        start.setActionCommand("start");
        apply.setActionCommand("apply");
        invert.setActionCommand("invert");
    }
    public void SetColor(Color color)
    {
        if(Color.white.equals(color))
        {
            current.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            qt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            sell.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            buy.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else
        {
            current.setForeground(Color.white);
            qt.setForeground(Color.white);
            sell.setForeground(Color.white);
            buy.setForeground(Color.white);
        }
        current.setBackground(color);
        qt.setBackground(color);
        sell.setBackground(color);
        buy.setBackground(color);
    }
    public void Menu()
    {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        if(m==null)
        {
            JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
            menu.add(control);
            menu.add(control1);
            menu.add(control2);
            menu.add(control3);
            menu.setLocation(new Point(name.getLocationOnScreen().x,name.getLocationOnScreen().y+20));
            menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
            menu.setVisible(true);
            m = menu;
            Kosilshik.m.add(menu);
        }else
        {
            m.setLocation(new Point(name.getLocationOnScreen().x,name.getLocationOnScreen().y+20));
            m.setVisible(true);
        }
        Kosilshik.allow=true;
        //menu.setLocation(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //Menu();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Menu();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

In order to render and edit I have a custom renderer.

```
public class Render implements TableCellRenderer
{
static 
{
    font= new Font(Config.config.getFont(), Font.BOLD, Config.config.getFontSize());
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
{
    return (Component) value;
}

}
```

My table model looks like so

```
public class PositionTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
private final List<kosilkshik.Position> local;
public PositionTableModel(List<kosilkshik.Position> list)
{
    local = list;
}
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
{
    return true;
}
@Override
public int getRowCount(){return local.size();}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {return 12;}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
{
    kosilkshik.Position pos = local.get(local.size()-rowIndex-1);
    switch (columnIndex) 
    {
        case 0:                
            return pos.view.name;
        case 1:
            return pos.view.qt;
        case 2:
            return pos.view.current;
        case 3:
            return pos.view.buy;
        case 4:
            return pos.view.sell;
        case 5:
            return pos.view.bid;
        case 6:
            return pos.view.avg;
        case 7:
            return pos.view.ask;
        case 8:
            return pos.view.mkt;
        case 9:
            return pos.view.p;
        case 10:
            return pos.view.flip;
        case 11:
            return pos.view.invert;
        default:
            return pos.view.name;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Once you click on component it switches to editor mode. So you need to dispose of editor by calling either

```
table.editingStopped(new ChangeEvent(Component)) // the component that was selected
```

or its canceled analog

Answer (score 1):

Read the `AbstractTableModel` API.

Whenever you change the data in the TableModel, the TableModel must invoke the appropriate `fireXXX(...)`, which will tell the table to repaint itself.

Comment: The real feeds were working properly , I never properly released the editor.